# jquery .next isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

take this simple code:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="box">abc</div>
    <div class="box" id="secondbox">abc</div>
    <div>generic</div>
    <div>generic</div>

</div>
```

Now I add the class box to let's say the last div generic:

```
$('#container div:last').addClass('box');
```

Now if i try to select the next .box with this it doesnt' work:

```
$('#secondbox').next('.box')
```

returns .length=0

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#container p:last').addClass('box');` be `$('#container div:last').addClass('box');`?

Comment: `$('#container p:last').addClass('box');` should be `$('#container div:last').addClass('box');` to do what you think you're doing (wll, not quite; see @lonesomeday's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015332/jquery-next-isnt-working/6015371#6015371)). Use a real-time DOM inspector (e.g., [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) to verify that your DOM manipulation has the desired outcome.

Comment: sorry yes of course it was div:last

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume what you actually mean is `#container div:last`.

[`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) does *not* find the next element that matches a selector.  It finds the next sibling element.  If you supply a selector, it tests the element against that selector.  If the test fails, an empty selection (i.e. `length == 0`) is returned.

You need [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll%5D):

```
$('#secondbox').nextAll('.box').first();
```

Comment: Isn't the difference between next and nextAll, that next returns only next sibling that matches filter and nextAll returns all siblings that match filter? So next should work too.

Comment: @enoyhs No. From the API reference (link above): "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."

Comment: just a note is `.first` the same as `nextAll()[0]` ? Because i don't think we need to call a method if that's a simple array xD

Comment: @yes123 No, `first` returns a jQuery selection. `[0]` retrieves the native DOM element.

Comment: that basically means if i do `[0]` i can't use jquery stuff like: `[0].doWhatever()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `$('#container p:last').addClass('box');` with `$('#container div:last').addClass('box');`

And as lonesomeday said. You should use nextAll selector.